# How to create a custom Maintenance page returning 503 for Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, http-status-code-503

I'm trying to set up a custom Maintenance page on MVC 3 but specifically on Azure. Basically to keep it SEO friendly i need to return a 503 (Service Unavailable). All my other custom error pages work in Azure (eg 404) following the usual

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.htm"/>
  <error statusCode="503" redirect="503.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```

The 404 page works but the 503 is not  followed and i simply get an ugly service unavailable page. I have the 500 error working fine through error.cshtml and the standard HandleErrorAttribute.

I even try returning my own ActionResult from an ActionFilter by using the following

```
public class SiteDownForTestingResult : ActionResult
{
    public SiteDownForTestingResult() : base()
    {
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/app_testing.htm");

        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.Clear();
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable;
        response.StatusDescription = "Service Unavailable.";
        response.WriteFile(path);
        response.End();
    }

}
```

were app_testing is my custom page, and then setting the `filterContext.Result = new SiteDownForTestingResult();` from OnActionExecuting of an ActionFilter and still i'm greeted by the plain 503 'service unavailable' page

Is this something to do with application.config on Azure locking something or other i don't know about. This works fine on IIS7 and my local box, but the Emulator and Cloud both give no joy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding custom 503 error is generated directly from https.sys mostly when app pool is not available. And now when there is no app pool none of your setting is going to work at your custom error settings will be specific to app pool. Also most of the search engine depend on 503 error code in return so display search result properly and that's why customization of this error is not typically done at application level.

As you referenced Windows Azure Emulator, I believe you are using Windows Azure Web Role. With Windows Azure Web Role you can customize IIS with AppCmd.exe in a StartUp task, which is your maximum level of customization. You can not reach HTTP.sys level of customization in Windows Azure so customization 503 error may not work on Windows Azure.